# Clean up XYZ coordinates with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-coordinates

I'm a python noob with no coding experience, trying to cleanup million plus XYZ coordinates using python and pandas. Here is my attempt to delete duplicate records, isolate XY pairs and Z outliers.
I am looking for guidance structuring the code and feedback on my approach, thank you for any help you can provide.

1. DataSample.csv

   - 321968.1709,184403.3476,5618.0000 <-Good record
   - 321969.8475,184415.2021,5619.0000 <-Good record
   - 321971.5702,184403.5676,5618.0000 <-Keep first record of duplicates
   - 321971.5702,184403.5676,5618.0000
2. If X and Y pairs are the same but Z values are different export to separate csv for review

   - 321974.7553,184449.9033,5623.0000
   - 321974.7553,184449.9033,6532.0000
   - 321974.7553,184449.9033,5824.0000
3. If Z values are out of range export to separate csv for review

   - 321976.5702,184442.0976,-9999.9999
   - 321976.8338,184458.6112,0.0000
   - 327847.0101,182355.2149,1.0

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ["x", "y", "z"]
df = pd.read_csv("DataSample.csv", names=cols)
unique_xyz = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x', 'y', 'z'], keep='first')
clean_xy_dup = pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(subset=['x', 'y'])
z_outlier = pandas.DataFrame.std(subset=['z'])
```

Comment: _I am looking for guidance structuring the code and feedback on my approach_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how to complete steps two and three in my post. The last two lines of my code are just place holders to what I think I should be doing.

Comment: I'm not sure about #2, but #3 should be easy, it's a simple conditional.